# java 8 Optional map() throw NPE with function reference but not with full lambda syntax

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

Is this a bug or a feature?

Below fails with NPE

```
Function<String, String> f = null;
Optional.<String>empty().map(f).orElse(null);
```

But not

```
Function<String, String> f = null;
Optional.<String>empty().map(value -> f.apply(value)).orElse(null);
```

IntelliJ for example would suggest to replace the second expression by the first one as equivalent, which made sense to me, until now.

The reason for this behavior is the implementation of `Optional#map()`:

```
public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    // check happens before the branching
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent())
        return empty();
    else {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```

Instead, if `map()` was implemented with:

```
public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    if (!isPresent())
        return empty();
    else {
        // the check happens only when relevant
        Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```

we would get a consistent behavior between the first 2 snippets. Any reason why `map()` is not the second implementation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug because it is explicitely documented. Quoting [`Optional.map(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) Javadoc:

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it [...]
>   
> ...
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the mapping function is `null`

So the `map` method always throw a `NullPointerException`, regardless of the presence of a value or not, if the `mapper` given is `null`: this explains the exception in the first case. However, the mapper is only applied if there is a value: this explains why there is no exception in the second case.

Comment: Good catch. Any idea why not checking for a null function only if the function is actually called?

Comment: @matthieus That I'm afraid I cannot say. I couldn't find any mail from the OpenJDK mailing list about this (it is most likely opinion-based).

Comment: Actually it's really weird that [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) works in different way: it throws NPE only if supplier is null *and* value is not present. Paul Sandoz [agreed](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-September/035426.html) that `orElseGet` specification was done this way by mistake.

Comment: In case someone is getting confused, this email is arguing in a different direction than I am. Note that the email indirectly answers my question about "why": it mentions consistency with the other methods on Optional, so I guess flatMap and filter are implied, and to NPE as early as possible. The behavior is not consistent with ifPresent() and orElseGet() though. Ah well, I won't sweat it and live with it I suppose!

Comment: In general, we strive to validate method parameters early (fail fast, promote failure atomicity, etc).  This often extends to checking parameters that may end up not be used.  (Of course, in a codebase that spans as much time, code, and developers as the JDK does, general principles like these are unlikely to be implemented with perfect consistency.)